# Double execution on a single click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having a problem when i click on an input(button) (click event captured using jquery) it is executed two times but the click event is single... i used **"e.stopPropagation();"** - but it didn't work...

```
jQuery("#ok").click(function(e){
       alert("Alert");
       e.stopPropagation();
});
```

i need the reason and the solution...

take care..

Comment: post your code...so that we can understand whats going on...

Comment: May be you somehow ran this click-setup code twice?

Comment: @maksymko... no brother just once..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**problem is solved...**

i just added `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` to the click function... and it worked... None of the following functions worked...

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
return false
```

---------------------CODE---------------------

```
jQuery("#ok").click(function(e){
       alert("Alert");
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Click here for more information on [jQuery Events](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)..

Answer (score 4):

Please use `e.stop(true,true)` and function which you are using. like

```
e.stop(true,true).show();
```

Comment: well i am getting an error.. which says that e.stop(true,true) is not a function... :(

Comment: if you are other work on another element then please use that element with stop function. like we wanna show any hidden div on button click then   $('#ok').click(function(){ $('div').stop(true,true).show();});.  Please let me know the process.

Answer (score 3):

I think you use this code as below:

```
jQuery("#ok").click(function(){
   alert("Alert");
   return false;
```

});

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault()` is likely what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i used

```
return false;
```

after the desired action.